# Styles form app.xaml not found by the designer

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I've just noticed than my xaml editor cannot see styles defined in App.xaml.

```
<Application x:Class="MyApp.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="Windows\MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Assets/Themes/ShinyBlue.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

            // this one gets a warning that's never used, though it is
            <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="backgroundBrush" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource NormalBrushGradient3}" Offset="0.1" />
                <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource NormalBrushGradient1}" Offset="0.4" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
```

Every call to such a style is underlined and neither of the styles is loaded by designer (everything is back and white). When I run the app it all looks well - style are being loaded.

Recently I changed the entry point to my app:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    [System.STAThreadAttribute()]
    public static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dirsToCreate = new[]
            {
                Settings.Default.PhotosDirectory
            };
        foreach (var dir in dirsToCreate)
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
        }

        App app = new App();
        app.InitializeComponent();
        app.Run();

        return 0;
    }
```

I suspect, but cannot be sure that this changed entry point may have something to do with that (I changed MainWinow's build action to 'Page').

Any ideas what's going on and how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

1. Since you changed your entry point, did you change your "StartupUri" attribute in the app.xaml to the new window you want to launch?
2. What is your x:Class attribute in your app.xaml file and what is your x:Class attribute in your startupwindow.xaml file?
3. Have you tried referencing your styles as a DynamicResource instead of a StaticResource?  A DynamicResource won't load your styles at compile time, it will load them at run-time.  You won't see your styles applied in the Design window when editing but the styles will be applied when you run your application.  This may not be the best way to fix this problem, but I have done it in the past just to get over some stupid little hurdles.  Personally, I never use the designer window, I just write my UI all in XAML so this wasn't really an issue for me.

Give these a try and let me know if any of them work for you.

Comment: See the xaml now, I included a few lines more. I guess 1) and 2) are ok. I tried 3) too but still I get the styles underlined. Btw even though the styles are not loaded in the designer they are loaded when I run the app. (even as StaticResource)

Comment: hmm, it sounds like it is loading the styles dynamically even though you are referencing them as a static resource.  In the past, I have solved this problem by either right clicking on the solution in the solution explorer and clicking clean solution and then rebuild solution, restarting visual studio and/or restarting the computer.

Comment: I doesn't help, still the same.